# Xpage window.focus() not working

Tags: window, focus, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have an Xpage which opens the popUp window on click, Just for the example I have created 2 buttons namely "popUp_form_clientSide" and "popUp_form_serverSide"

popUp_form_clientSide having event on client side which is calling the "doPopup()" function.
popUp_form_serverSide calling the same function but from server-side with the help of `view.postScript("doPopup()");`

doPopup() is loaded client side in a script.

Xpage code:

```xml
 <xp:button value="popUp_form_clientSide" id="button4">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var link ="http://google.com";
        doPopup(link);]]>
       </xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
 </xp:button>


<xp:button value="popUp_form_serverSide" id="button3">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="button4">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var link ="xx_openConfigPageN.xsp?docName=K1&pageName=K1&action=newDocument"
view.postScript("doPopup('"+link+"');")}]]>
    </xp:this.action>
   </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

javaScript doPopup() code:

```js
var popupWindow = null;
var  doPopup = function (link)
{
  if (popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed)
    {
      popupWindow.focus();
     alert("In focus")
    }
  else
    {
     popupWindow = window.open(link,"New",
        "width=200,height=200");
    alert("New");
    }
  };
```

Now if I click on Client side button it works properly for example it opens the popup with passed variable link and if I click again it checks whether already opened and focus the window instead of opening new.So this is perfect,

But when I click on server side button, It opens the popup nomally which is perfect and when I click it again it goes inside the if condition alerts the "In focus" message but does not put the window in front(window.focus()),

Very frequently it focuses the window but not always , in Contrast the client side button works perfect.

I dont know whats wrong I am doing here, Or is there any other good way to do focus on window if already opened.

I want to get it work from server-side because the link variable contains lots of content from database and conditions,So I choose the serverSide to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Ajit,
Stick with the client side version of your JavaScript. You can inject server side values using #{...} inside a client side script tag.

You might want to revisit your popup approach, you are bound to create a support nightmare:

- popup blockers might prevent it
- when you click on the main window the popup gets hidden and might not pop back when focused
- sucks on mobile devices

Alternatives:

- ExtLib dialog control
- dynamically show dialog content based on button

Comment: Yes. I am actually aware of using #{...} , but not only the component value ,I need the documents count from a view as well as document ids too, So that is why chose server side scripting. ant idea ho to do this now??

Comment: Ajit: For the data portion I have used a REST service invoked upon opening the dialog. It can be built in SSJS or JAVA and are relatively simple to invoke.

Comment: Short version: don't. Long version:compute what you need ssjs into a scope variable as json string and insert it into your client side script. Putting a client side interaction into the middle of a rest call is never a good idea. And don't use a popup